# How can I customize the default indent in the Chrome Javascript console to be 2 spaces?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It's strange to me that given the Chrome console is written for JS, and the JS standard indent size is two spaces- that using tab in the console gives 4 spaces. I'm new to JS and wanted to change this setting so that pressing 'tab' while in the console gives 2 spaces but can't find instructions on how to customize it.

I tried following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/customize) on customizing Chrome Dev tools, but can't get past the first step. They say to open the Main Menu to access preferences but seem to be referring to a Dev Tools main menu (vs Chrome's menu), which I can't find.

Anything helps! Thanks.

Comment: Its a little vertical ... at the top right of the chrome dev console then settings

Comment: Thanks @Deckerz! Yep, that was it. And I found the default indent spaces option at the bottom of the main preferences screen. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option can be found here:

[image: Settings button]

From that menu choose "Settings", alternatively press F1 to jump there.

[image: Menu option]

The option is located in the "Preferences" section under the "Sources" heading.

[image: Setting location]

Comment: Thanks @ericd7 for the detailed answer and helpful screenshots. This definitely works- and though you seem to be doing it in localhost, the menus and locations of settings are basically the same in the Chrome browser's built-in dev tools.